# openpyxl - is it possible to change marker on linechart to None

Tags: openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to modify my xlsx data i create few linecharts. I can't figure it out how to change Marker options on my chart to None. When graph is created Marker Options in xlsx is set to Automatic so I have a lot of dots on the line.

Tnaks for answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in openpyxl 2.3. The docs are still work in progress but you have full access to entire formatting API. Unfortunately, this API is hideously complex.

Code will look something like:

```
chart = LineChart()
# add some data
line = chart.series[0]
line.shapeProperties.line.noFill = True
line.marker.symbol = "circle"
```

See http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/stable/charts/introduction.html to get a start (and checkout the 2.3 branch for more examples). For full control you will have to familiarise yourself with the OOXML specification and be prepared to read the source of your charts.